# I need help working with <string, char> format dictionaries in C#

Tags: c#, .net, windows, forms, dictionary

This post is about a difficulty that I am having in C# (Windows Forms App in Visual Studio 2017, .NET Framework) regarding the use of a Dictionary in a "string, char" format.

Here is what I have:

First - a dictionary in a format

```
Dictionary<String, char> bintoascii = new Dictionary<String, char>()
{
    { "01000001" , 'A'},
    { "01000010" , 'B'},
    //..................
    { "01111010" , 'z'},
    { "00100000" , ' ' },
};
```

And the actual conversion code:

```
AsciiOutput.Text = "";

String binninput = Input.Text;

for (int i = 0; i < binninput.Length; i++)
{
    if (i > 0)
        AsciiOutput.Text = AsciiOutput.Text + " ";
    else if (i == 0)
    {
        AsciiOutput.Text = AsciiOutput.Text + " ";
    }

    string b = binninput[i].ToString();

    if (bintoascii.ContainsKey(b))
        AsciiOutput.Text = AsciiOutput.Text + (bintoascii[b]);
}
```

The function of this code is to convert from binary to ASCII via input and output textboxes (which have already been successfully set up on my GUI).

Essentially, it first declares a dictionary of Binary values (represented as strings) and their corresponding ASCII values (represented as chars).

The textbox that binary is inputted to is Input.Text and the textbox that ASCII is outputted from is AsciiOutput.Text (Note: the string binninput represents Input.Text)

There is a loop based on the length of the Input (binninput/Input.Text) that places spaces between each letter of binary. So it would be 01000001 01000010 instead of 0100000101000010, for example.

The latter part of the loop inserts the 8-digit binary representation of each letter individually (hence why it is repeated based on the length of the input).

Visual Studio displays no errors, but the output textbox (AsciiOutput.Text) is blank on my GUI. I'm not for sure on this, but I think that the issue lies within the

```
string b = binninput[i].ToString();
```

line of code. Removing the .ToString() function causes conversion errors. I've tried for hours messing around with substituting chars, ints, and strings around thinking it's a basic mistake but to no resolve, hence why I came here.

(Using a char, string format dictionary I got ASCII to binary conversions working great and the code look very similar; if someone wants I can post that here too)

Comment: The best way for you to solve your problem is to use debugger and breakpoints. Try to put a breakpoint inside your last condition (if contains..) and see if it will hit? Why is it not hitting? What value is it trying to check inside the dictionary?

Comment: Also check your first condition inside the loop. It looks like you are doing the same thing no matter what? ;-)

Comment: If `binninput` is a `string`, then `binninput[i].ToString()` is a single character. `bintoascii.ContainsKey(b)` will always be false because keys to `bintoascii` are always multi-character strings, never single characters.

Comment: How about using built-in libraries? Like ASCII encoding: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.asciiencoding.getstring?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: You are searching the dictionary `Key` for a character instead of a string when you do `if (bintoascii.ContainsKey(b))`. Do you mean to have a `Dictionary<char, string>` instead? Or do you mean to search the values and get the corresponding `Key`?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you're trying to do is look up a `Key` (the binary string) from a given `Value` (a character from some input string).

One way to do this is to use the `System.Linq` extension method `FirstOrDefault` (which returns the first match or the default for the type if no match is found), use `Value == character` as the match critera, and get the `Key` from the result:

```
// This would return "01000001" in your example above
var result = bintoascii.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value == 'A').Key;
```

Here's a brief code sample that populates a dictionary with the string representation of the binary values for the characters representing all the numbers, uppercase and lowercase letters, and the space character, then parses an input string (`"Hello @ World"`) and returns the `Key` for each character found in a `Value` in the dictionary (if the value is missing, then it displays the character in square brackets - I added the `'@'` character to the test string to show what it would look like):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // Populate dictionary with string binary key and associated char value
    Dictionary<String, char> binToAscii =
        Enumerable.Range(32, 1)               // Space character
            .Concat(Enumerable.Range(48, 10)) // Numbers
            .Concat(Enumerable.Range(65, 26)) // Uppercase Letters
            .Concat(Enumerable.Range(97, 26)) // Lowercase Letters
            .Select(intVal => (char) intVal)  // Convert int to char
            // And finally, set the key to the binary string, padded to 8 characters
            .ToDictionary(dataChar => Convert.ToString(dataChar, 2).PadLeft(8, '0'));

    var testString = "Hello @ World";

    // Display the binary representation of each character or [--char--] if missing
    var resultString = string.Join(" ", testString.Select(chr =>
        binToAscii.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value == chr).Key ?? $"[--'{chr}'--]"));

    Console.WriteLine($"{testString} ==\n{resultString}");

    GetKeyFromUser("\nDone! Press any key to exit...");
}
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! I found this very helpful.